# How to install ubuntu restricted extras but not flash?

Tags: flash, software-installation

Like the title says! i just want to know how to install Ubuntu Restricted Extras without the flash packages.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Restricted extras is a metapackage

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MetaPackages

A metapackage is not a single package, but rather a list of packages.

The idea is to make it easier for you, rather then installing each individual package, you install the metapackage.

To see the list of packages in restricted extras see

http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/ubuntu-restricted-extras

which points to

http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/ubuntu-restricted-addons

So ...

```
sudo apt-get install gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg gstreamer0.10-fluendo-mp3 gstreamer0.10-pitfdll gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad-multiverse libavcodec-extra-53 ttf-mscorefonts-installer unrar
```

Comment: well, i decided to not install it by that way because it asks for missing dependencies and i honestly don't have the patience to looking for them (now i understand why they put everything in a metapackage), but now i know how i should do. Definitely a good answer.

Comment: As of the day of this comment, there are missing packages for the packages 'gstreamer0.10-pitfdll' and 'libavcodec-extra-53'. So, remove them from the above code and run it in the terminal.